# There is no route defined for key X - two StackNavigators

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `react-navigation` library to navigation.

but when I want to use two `StackNavigator`s I got this error:

> There is no route defined for key X must be one of ....

this error when appear that I want navigation `Screen1` from first `StackNavigator` to `Screen2` from second `StackNavigator`.

my `router.js`:

```
export const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
  Splash: {
    screen: Splash,
  },
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },

},
{

  initialRouteName: 'Splash',

});



export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({

  KasianServices:{
    screen:KasianServices,
  },
  SpecialOffers:{
    screen:SpecialOffers,
  },

},
{
  initialRouteName: 'KasianServices',

});




export const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  LoginStack: {
    screen: LoginStack,
  },
  HomeStack:{
    screen: HomeStack,
  },
},{
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'LoginStack',
}

);

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Stack: { screen: RootNavigator },
},{
    contentComponent: RightSideMenu,
    drawerPosition: 'right',
})
```

for example:

```
Splash ==> navigation('KasianServices') ==> I got this error.
```